# Postgres returns the last item on the array instead the first

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have on my controller something like

```
@account = @user.accounts.first
```

where I only want to display the first item in the accounts array. But whenever I add a new account, @account now refers to the last item in the accounts array.

Locally, with SQLite3, it works correctly, @account always refers to the first item in the accounts array, but on heroku with postgresql, is when that happens.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9598) in the rails repository, you should explicitly state the ordering to ensure this works correctly:

```
@account = @user.accounts.order(:created_at).first
```

Comment: Nice hat..you got.. :)

Comment: Also this info on Postgres ordering may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/13191075/2463468

Comment: I eventually found a similar issue here on SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525858/increment-counter-and-rails-first-using-postgresql-strange-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Postgres tables do not have an implicit order. If you want a guaranteed order, you need to add `.order` to your query:

```
@account = @user.accounts.order(id: :asc).first
```

would give you the first account created for this user,

```
@account = @user.accounts.order(id: :desc).first
```

the last.