# default sort order for an activerecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

if i didn't set a default_scope in a model(Account), and just call Account.first, which item will be returned ?

here is an axample:
Account table have 5 records, Account.all returns:

```
  Account.all.map{ |x| {id: x.id, name: x.name, created_at: x.created_at, updated_at:x.updated_at}}
  Account Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts"
=> [{:id=>2,
  :name=>"Hessel, Kirlin and Gulgowski",
  :created_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:33 EDT -04:00,
  :updated_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:33 EDT -04:00},
 {:id=>3,
  :name=>"Hessel, Kirlin and Gulgowski",
  :created_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:34 EDT -04:00,
  :updated_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:34 EDT -04:00},
 {:id=>4,
  :name=>"Hessel, Kirlin and Gulgowski",
  :created_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:34 EDT -04:00,
  :updated_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:34 EDT -04:00},
 {:id=>5,
  :name=>"Hessel, Kirlin and Gulgowski",
  :created_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:35 EDT -04:00,
  :updated_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:35 EDT -04:00},
 {:id=>1,
  :name=>"EIS",
  :created_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:31 EDT -04:00,
  :updated_at=>Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:44:32 EDT -04:00}]
```

Account.first return the record with id 2, i didn't set the default_scope in model, why id with 2 not id with 1?

thanks !

update: i like this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986620/655621)

Comment: What query does the Account.first method produce?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that in the absence of an order a default order by id would be used, but this does not seem to be the case in 3.2.13 at least

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > Book.first
  Book Load (60.0ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" LIMIT 1
```

So maybe there has been a code change in recent versions. What version are you using?

Comment: i'm using rails 3.2.13 for this

Comment: Check the query then: it looks like it doesn't order. If ordering is critical to you then I'd specify it explicitly anyway.